# "No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file." error with Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm using Moq to provide a mocking context for my Oracle db. But when I call `_context.Entry` with the mocked context, I get an `InvalidOperationException`.

`"No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file."`

I'm already providing a mocked context, so not sure why it's still trying to read connection string to create the context.

```
// generated code for oracle db
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ACTIVITY_CODE> ACTIVITY_CODE { get; set; }
}

// my code
public partial class Entities : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public Entities(string scon) : base(scon) { }
}

// my code
public partial class ActivityCodeService
{
    private Entities _context;

    public ActivityCodeService(Entities context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
    public ACTIVITY_CODE Update(ACTIVITY_CODE item)
    {
        ACTIVITY_CODE ret = null;
        var found = Read(item.ACT_ID);
        if (found != null)
        {
            _context.Entry<ACTIVITY_CODE>(found).CurrentValues.SetValues(item); // throws InvalidOperationException "No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file."
            _context.SaveChanges();
            ret = item;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

// test code
[TestMethod]
public void activity_code_update_test()
{
    // arrange
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<ACTIVITY_CODE>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<ACTIVITY_CODE>>().Setup(o => o.Provider).Returns(testData.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<ACTIVITY_CODE>>().Setup(o => o.Expression).Returns(testData.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<ACTIVITY_CODE>>().Setup(o => o.ElementType).Returns(testData.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<ACTIVITY_CODE>>().Setup(o => o.GetEnumerator()).Returns(testData.GetEnumerator());

    var mockContext = new Mock<Entities>();
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.ACTIVITY_CODE).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var expected = new ACTIVITY_CODE() { ACT_ID = 1, ACT_CODE = "code 2", ACT_DESC = "desc 2" };
    var target = new ActivityCodeService(mockContext.Object);

    // act
    target.Update(expected);
}
```

But if I don't use `_context.Entry`, then the test runs fine which is expected. So does that mean `_context.Entry` is creating another internal context and ignoring my mocked context?

```
// my code
public ACTIVITY_CODE Update(ACTIVITY_CODE item)
{
    var ret = _context.ACTIVITY_CODE.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ACT_ID == item.ACT_ID);
    if (ret != null)
    {
        ret.ACT_CODE = item.ACT_CODE;
        ret.ACT_DESC = item.ACT_DESC;
        _context.SaveChanges(); // this will work fine with Moq's mocked context
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Entry` isn't, and can't be, mocked by Moq as it's not virtual so it is still going to try to use the database that it believes is there. That's why it's looking for a connection string.

What I *have* been able to do which has worked well is to abstract that function call into a virtual method that I had enough control over to actually mock.

---

**Alternatives:**
There are some tools based on answers to other questions that have the same base problem. Looks like *TypeMock* and *JustMock* may be able to work around the issue.

Additionally, it looks like MS Fakes should be able to shim it. After a little investigation it looks like it'd work something like this:

```
ShimDbEntityEntry<TestModel> entryMock = new ShimDbEntityEntry<TestModel>();
ShimDbPropertyValues mockValues = new ShimDbPropertyValues();
mockValues.SetValuesObject = (newValues) => { }; // Manually do something here
entryMock.CurrentValuesGet = () => mockValues;
ShimDbContext.AllInstances.EntryOf1M0<TestModel>((ctx, target) => entryMock);
```